# Send byte array to Java Server from IOS client using native Objective C VIA TCP Socket

Tags: java, objective-c, serversocket

Im trying to build an socket based Chat application . For server im using Java enterprise . And in my client side IOS application im using native objective C . I need to pass some byte Array from my client to server . 
Here is my code so far what i,m trying

Server Code :

```
public void run() {
        try {
            this.dIn = new DataInputStream(serviceSocket.getInputStream());
            while(!serviceSocket.isClosed()){
                 Object respObj = new Object();
        try {
            int length= dIn.readInt();//= dIn.readByte();                    // read length of incoming message



           // System.out.println("Av :"+ dIn.available());
          //  System.out.println("length :" + dIn.readInt());
            if(length>0) {
                byte[] message = new byte[length];
                dIn.readFully(message, 0, message.length); // read the message
                ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(message);
                ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(b);
                try {
                    respObj = o.readObject();
                   // System.out.println(respObj.toString());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                System.out.println(obj.getClass());
                System.out.println(obj.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Client Code :

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"192.168.1.10", 9025, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream =  (__bridge NSInputStream*)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream*)writeStream;
    inputStream.delegate = self;
    outputStream.delegate = self;

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];

    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:self.app.authCredential forKey:@"aut"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];


    long l = 1165620611;
    char bytes[sizeof(long)];
    memcpy(bytes,&l,sizeof(l));

    int size = sizeof(bytes)/sizeof(char);

    NSLog(@"Size Of Byte Array: %d",size);


    NSData *dataSize = [NSData dataWithBytes: &size length: sizeof(size)];
    NSData *dataT = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:size];

    [outputStream write:dataSize.bytes maxLength:dataSize.length];
    [outputStream write:dataT.bytes maxLength:dataT.length];

    [outputStream close];
```

After passing the data into server its showing some garbage value against the Byte length. possibly in the readInt() function not working as expected .